# Applications of self-adjoint and unitary operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In my study of linear algebra, I have found applications to physics can often help getting the picture. With this respect what are practical use cases where adjoint transformations of the form $$\langle f(u), v\rangle=\left\langle u, f^{*}(v)\right\rangle$$ are helpful?

Do not just mention "quantum mechanics" but show how they provide insight of the physical system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In quantum mechanics, physical observables are described by self adjoint operators. The reason for this is that their eigenvalues are all real, and their eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis to the Hilbert space of states of the system. Each state can be expressed as a sum of eigenstates of the operator, where each eigenstate corresponds to some specific (real) eigenvalue:
$$|\psi\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n|\phi_n\rangle$$

Each eigenvalue represents a possible outcome of a physical measurement (that's why it needs to be real and not complex), and the probability of measuring that specific outcome given the state $|\psi\rangle$ is given by -

$$P(A=\lambda_n)=|\langle\psi|\phi_n\rangle|^2=|c_n|^2$$

As you can see, this formulation uses the two main properties of a self-adjoint operator - the orthonormal set of eigenvectors, and the real set of eigenvalues.

Unitary operators are used to represent evolution of states of a system. The reason to use unitary operators for this is since they naturally respect the structure of the given orthonormal basis (they don't affect inner product), and their eigenvalues are all of norm $1$ (and so they don't change the overall probability measure). For instance, the unitary time evolution operator is defined as - $$U|\phi_n\rangle=|\phi_n\rangle e^{-i\frac{\lambda_n}{\hbar}t}$$

When this operator acts on a state, it described how the state changes over time - $$U|\psi\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n|\phi_n\rangle e^{-i\frac{\lambda_n}{\hbar}t}$$

As you can see, the operator keeps the state normalized at all times $t$, and preserves the natural structure of the orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space.

There are plenty more examples, and one could talk about this topic for literally as long as you'd like, but this is the "in a nutshell" explanation - self-adjoint and unitary operators are useful since the are unitarily diagonalizable (which is always useful), and preserve some of the more "natural" properties we'd like to have in a Hilbert space representing a physical system.

This example is purely from quantum mechanics, but these operators are of course useful in plenty of other topics.